# Is tag for [bug] needed when "We are not a formal GIS Software Support Site"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

On our [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page we say explicitly with some bolding:

> **We are not a *formal* GIS Software Support Site** and are likely to close questions and recommend you seek official routes for support if
>   you:
>
> - ...
> - seem to be trying to submit bug reports and enhancement requests here instead of direct to the vendor/development team of the software
>     involved.

However, I note that on Main GIS SE we currently have 4 questions tagged [bug](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) after burninating the previous 23.

Is the [bug](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag on Main GIS SE needed or should it be [burninated and then blacklisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/215590)?

Note that this is not a question about the Meta tag named [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because Meta GIS SE provides support for Main GIS SE.

Comment: What is Burninate?

Comment: @mapBaker http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/215590

Comment: The [tag:bug] tag has resurrected - is it time to re-burninate and blacklist? cc @AndreSilva

Comment: The [tag:bug] has now been blacklisted. cc @AndreSilva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After implementing the [burnination advocated](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4064/115), I think we need to go the next step and blacklist the [bug](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag because it has resurrected with 4 questions since we last succeeded in burninating it.

Answer (score 14):

I support Burninating this tag, because it is pretty much a Meta Tag. It does not give any additional information about the question, and most of the time, the issue might not even be a Bug.

Comment: In light of @AndreSilva's comment (on the question) about burninating but not blacklisting, are you saying to just burninate it or to blacklist it too?  Our blacklist currently comprises just `gis`, `geospatial` and `spatial`.

Comment: I'm fine with just burniating this tag; We can talk about blacklisting it, if it really becomes a major problem.

Comment: The [tag:bug] tag has now been burninated (i.e. no longer appears) but I have not requested its blacklisting because, as you and @AndreSilva say, that would probably be overkill.

Comment: The [tag:bug] tag has resurrected - is it time to re-burninate and blacklist? cc @AndreSilva

Answer (score 0):

I hardly doubt that SE attracts questions about bugs just because the tag exist, so I think removing the tag will not keep people from asking the wrong questions. So yes, perhaps it should be burned. But no, it will not keep people from asking the wrong questions.